# How condition variables work and store in memory in Java?

Tags: java, performance, variables, conditional-statements, final

```java
//Case1
if(a > 5){
    //..
}

//Case2
private static final int NUM1 = 5;
if(a > NUM1){
    //..
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////

//Case3
if(a > 6 + b){
    //..
}

//Case4
private static final int NUM2 = 6;
if(a > NUM2  + b){
    //..
}
```

In [Java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_(programming_language))
1. How *if* condition's variables work in java? (for example: *if(a > 5)* how 5 is stored in memory? like *final* or else?)
2. should i use case2 instead of case1 for more performance?
3. should i use case4 instead of case3 for more performance?

```java
for(int i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++){
    if(a > 5){}
    if(a > NUM){}
    if(a > 6 + b){}
    if(a > NUM  + b){}
}
```

4. if i get into the loop, is result change?

Comment: What do you mean in #4

Comment: #4 = if i get conditions into the loop, how 5 or 6 stored in memory? (is it same with case(1,2,3,4)?)

Comment: At a glance, I would expect #1 and #2 (and #3 and #4) to be compiled to exactly the same bytecode in the method implementation and have exactly the same performance characteristics.  Use whatever's most readable.

Comment: Why not test it if you're that concerned about miniscule performance differences?

Comment: @DaveNewton actually the question is not about performance, its about how variables stored in memory. (i know its very miniscule performance difference)

Comment: You should write for clarity and ignore "performance" implications of minor issues like this. Save performance concerns for algorithmic complexity and string concatenation.

Comment: The value "5" isn't a variable.

Comment: Oh, sorry, I guess I got confused after reading the pars that had the word "performance" in them-my bad.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I compiled code with these statements and disassembled.

As you can see, there is no difference for comparisons between integer literals, and comparisons for `public static final` primitives.

Curiously, on some JVMs the comparison (a>6+b) might be faster than (a>5), if `bipush` and `iadd` are more efficient than `iconst`. I'm personally not sure why `bipush` is used for cases 3 and 4 only. If someone could shed some light on this I would be interested.

```
// method 1; if(a>5)
  13: iload_1
  14: iconst_5
  15: if_icmple     25
  18: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  21: iconst_1
  22: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
// method 2; if(a>NUM1)
  25: iload_1
  26: iconst_5
  27: if_icmple     37
  30: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  33: iconst_2
  34: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
// method 3; if(a > 6+b)
  37: iload_1
  38: bipush        6
  40: iload_2
  41: iadd
  42: if_icmple     52
  45: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  48: iconst_1
  49: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
// method 4; if(a > 6+b)
  52: iload_1
  53: bipush        6
  55: iload_2
  56: iadd
  57: if_icmple     67
  60: getstatic     #4                  // Field java/lang/System.out:Ljava/io/PrintStream;
  63: iconst_1
  64: invokevirtual #5                  // Method java/io/PrintStream.println:(I)V
  67: return
```

Comment: What's surprising about the push? You're performing addition on a stack machine.

Comment: @chrylis I understand why `bipush` might be used to push the addend to the stack. I don't understand why the same isn't used when pushing 5 to the stack for the comparison in methods 1 and 2. As you can see, in the case of methods 1 and 2, `5` is being pushed to the stack by `iconst_5`, instead of consistently using `bipush` or `ldc`. As far as I can tell, `bipush` is very efficiently implemented in machine code (just copy byte, sign-extend, and push) while `iconst` might not be as optimizable since it has to copy value from class file's constant pool.

Comment: Ah, I see your issue now. What compiler is this?

Comment: @chrylis OpenJDK javac 1.8.0_40. It's a bit late right now but I'll take a look at [applicable JLS](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-3.html) when I can.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the JLS won't have anything to say, as those are both semantically identical. It's like choosing whether to branch on equal or not-equal.